# Accessing MySQLi connection from another class

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

This are my files atm:
- class.core.php
- class.site.php
- global.php

I'm trying to access the DB connection from Core to Site. I've tried everything and nothing works.

class.core.php:

```
class Core {

    public $db;

    public $host = "localhost";
    public $username = "root";
    public $password = "***";
    public $dbname = "***";

    public function __construct() {

        $this->db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
        if($this->db->connect_errno) {

            echo $this->db->connect_error();

            die();

        }

        return $this->db;

    }

}
```

class.site.php:

```
class Site {

    public $db;

    public function __construct(Core $db) {

        $this->db = $db->db;

    }

}
```

global.php:

```
require_once("_classes/class.core.php");
require_once("_classes/class.site.php");

$core = new Core();
$site = new Site();
```

I need all the help I can get. Thanks :)

Comment: .. or you could inject same instance of `MySQLi` in both constructors

Comment: maybe using `global $core`; in constructor of Site object an then `$this->db = $core->db;` ...

Comment: @user0000001 why would you want to introduce global variables? Especially since the same could be achieved by doing `$site = new Site($core);` .. although it would be a serious violation of of [LoD](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter)

Comment: @user0000001 It's not a question of getting Rep, it's a question of good coding practices, lookup SOLID/STUPID principles, GLOBAL/STATIC is one of the worst enemy to fight in development practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaking how constructors work. First of all constructors don't return anything, thus you should not return something from the constructor. I don't know (never tried) to return anything but it just looks strange in there.

Second you almost got the idea behind dependency injection... Site requires a DB, then inject a DB through its constructor like:

```
$core = new Core();
$site = new Site($core->db);
```

Becareful not to require too much for nothing, instead of requiring a core for your site to work, require a mysqli instead since thats what you want...

```
class Site {
    public $db;
    public function __construct(mysqli $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

This will segregate your dependencies a little and untie your code as much as possible.

Last but not least, avoid using die()/exit(), use exceptions, and handle them cleanly. Die is very impersonnal for the user and doesn't look good. Handle your exceptions such as database issues correctly by throwing exceptions and handling them in a beautiful way!

Else, there is no reason your current code won't work, it's something else that doesn't work and we can't see it!

Comment: Is there any reason why you did it only half-way? I mean, why are you pulling the DB connection out of `Core` instance, instead of creating DB connection externally and then injection it in both instances?

Comment: Thats what the user already had. It can always be interresting to keep the database in the core if that's what he wants, it's not a so bad practice, just creates a little, but oh so little tight coupling in this case. The Mysqli class is something generic, so the tight coupling is extremely low in this case.

Comment: Consider his CORE class to be a Plumber for many features... not a bad thing, you need plumbers even in good archs

Comment: I get a feeling that your "plumber" is covered somewhere in [resign patterns](http://www.fsfla.org/~lxoliva/fun/prog/resign-patterns). Also the `Core` class as such is already not only having computation in the constructor (which makes it extremely hard to test) but also violating [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and leaking encapsulation =/ Just my two cents.

Comment: Don't agree with OCP there, it has nothing to do with it, but i do agree with the testability. Yet again, if the goal of the core class is only to be a plumber of many other features, do you need to test it? Plumbers usually do no computation thus don't require testing. And no, plumbers are necessary, you need them at one point or another... A controller is a plumber, would you resign using controllers? Or do you like fat controllers instead? :P

Comment: Actually, controller has only one responsibility - to alter state of model layer and (rarely, mostly in desktop apps) the current view. Fat controllers tend to be a result of people placing either appication logic or UI logic, or both in said controllers.

Comment: @tereško Look up some documentation, modifying state is not part of the controller anymore, controller is just plain navigation/request logic. State alteration should be kept to a minimum even in controllers to provide maximum portability to other entry points that can't easily be mapped to the web routing strategy such as command line arguments! I think this discussion has gone far enough into comments, you're free to think what you want as do i :)

Comment: According to which "documentation"? Was it written by Fowler, Evans or Cunningham? Or the source of you "documentation" is some shitty framework, which just wants to use the term "MVC" for advertising?